# Создать собственный xml validator

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Дали задание написать свой собственный validator xml файла по xsd на java.
Нашел в интернете много различных онлайн валидаторов, но не понимаю как  они устроенны. Как именно происходит проверка на well-formed и валидность xml файла?

Comment: Онлайн валидаторы используют встроенные возможности языка. Будьте уверены, никому не вперлось писать собственный. Для Java есть `javax.xml.validation.Validator`, где все тривиально и в несколько срок. Вы уверены, что вас попросили именно писать собственную реализацию, а не просто написать XSD и прогнать через валидатор уже входящий в состав Java API? Если можно, выложите задание в исходном виде?

Comment: @enzo Здравствуйте, я знаю что в Java есть javax.xml.validation.Validator . Но опять же, я не могу понять как именно он проходит по xml и xsd документу. Доки смотрел.  Задание дословно - Написать простенький валидатор для проверки xml документа на синтаксическую корректность и соответствие примитивных типов с xsd

Comment: Мне приходит на ум только проходить по каждой строке и делать огромное количество проверок, но я сильно сомневаюсь что это будет работать быстро, поэтому хотел бы увидеть как работают стандартные валидаторы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что пакет `javax.xml` для работы с XML в Java включает в себя только абстракции (это API), а реализация [зависит от версии JDK](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXP). Имплементацию стандартного валидатора xerces можете посмотреть [тут](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xerces/java/trunk/src/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/validation/), но она далеко не простая и с вашим заданием врядли поможет.

> Задание дословно - Написать простенький валидатор для проверки xml
>   документа на синтаксическую корректность и соответствие примитивных
>   типов с xsd

Если понимать это задание также дословно как оно записано, то можно сделать так:

- Подготавливаете XSD документ. Включайте в него только примитивные типы, т.к. только они фигурируют в задании;
- Пишете XSD reader, который пробегает по XSD парсером и просто составляет словарь элементов в виде `LinkedHashMap`, где **key** - название элемента / тэга, **value** - [тип тэга](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#built-in-primitive-datatypes);
- Пишете простенький хэлпер с набором статических методов, который проверяют соответствие типа: `isInteger()`, `isDouble()` etc. Можно ограничиться только базовыми;
- Пишете сам валидатор, передаете ему схему и документ. Пробегаете по документу парсером и сверяетесь со словарем, который вы составили выше. На его базе можно кидать исключения, если: тэг отсуствует в схеме, тэг идет не в той последовательности, не совпадает тип элемента.

При желании все это можно построить на базе JAXP, с ErrorHadler'ом etc.

Если нужны комплексные типы, вложенность или более сложные условия, то потребуется построения более сложных constraints. В таких случаях вообще хорошо уточнять у интервьюера какие конкретно знания он хочет чтобы вы продемонстрировали, выдумая подобные синтетические задачи.